# Sublime Text 3 / Emmet – Select both opening & closing tag (via Shortcut)

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet

Just a quick question in order to optimize my workflow / productivity with Sublime Text 3 & Emmet...

So far I am able to (on Mac)

- select the opening and closing tag via **CMD + Shift + K**
- select the nested HTML / text of a wrapping attribute via **CMD + Shift + A**

But what I haven't found out yet is a way to *select the opening and closing tag completely* (with all possible values) in order to delete the surrounding tags.

To illustrate...

```
<span style="color: #660066;"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amed</strong></span>
```

Running **CMD + Shift + K** renders this selection:

[image]

...which  doesn't allow me to instantly delete the code.

Any ideas / hints / workarounds you can think of? I researched both the web and the Sublime Text docs but to no avail...

Thanks & regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlight the tag you want to remove the opening and closing tags for and try **CTRL +  SHIFT + ;**

That should delete the selected tag and it's closing partner.

The [emmet documentation](https://docs.emmet.io/actions/remove-tag/) has this as the remove tag shortcut, but states the shortcut is **CTRL + SHIFT + K**, when infact (on my setup at least), it's **CTRL + SHIFT + ;** in Sublime Text 3.

If this doesn't work, you should be able to find what the default key binding is by checking your default key bindings file under **Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Key Bindings - Default**. Run a search in this file for "remove_tag" and see what binding is attached to it.

If for some reason it doesn't exist or you'd like to change the binding, you can do so by editing your user key bindings file under **Preferences > Package Settings > Emmet > Key Bindings - User**.

Simply add:

```
 [
  {
    "keys": [
        "shift+ctrl+;"
    ], 
    "args": {
        "action": "remove_tag"
    }, 
    "command": "run_emmet_action", 
    "context": [
        {
            "key": "emmet_action_enabled.remove_tag"
        }
    ]
  }
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately it doesn't work for me... :-/

See this short [screencast](http://recordit.co/UkmKHsf4Pt), using **CTRL + SHIFT + A** & **CTRL + SHIFT + K** first to illustrate and then **CTRL + SHIFT + ;** but that only jumps to and selects the next attribute...?

Comment: I've updated my original answer with a possible solution. :)

Comment: Hello from the future! `remove_tag` is no longer bound to a hotkey by default, but the suggested binding is Cmd + '